# Any software to remove $NtUninstallxxxxx (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, uninstall

Any commercial or free software to give me a list and descriptions of patch uninstalls and let me remove selected ones?

I've tried Windows XP Update Remover, but seems it doesn't provide any information for majority of items and I have to delete one by one...

I also know I can do it manually, but just wondering if there is more professional software to make it more accurate and quick.

Comment: Do those even exist anymore? I can't find them on my Windows installation (7 in this case). I suspect that got scrapped in favor of Restore points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCleaner on XP gives the option to clean up hotfix installer files (it's under Advanced).

For general hard drive space saving techniques, I've found http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?id=40356&p=1 to be invaluable in keeping my 4gb Eee hard drive from filling up. Several of the less drastic tips may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [XP Remove Hotfix Backup](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/utils/xp_hotfix_backup.htm) (by Doug Knox, Former Microsoft MVP Windows Media Center/Desktop Systems) a try. This tool does not need any installation. It works for XP although it's old. Here is the [direct download link](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/utils/xp_remove_hotfix_backup.zip) to the tool (28 KB).

Comment: Well, I forgot to mentioned I tried that one, however it was able to find only part of the folders...

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could remember where I read it, but I do recall reading that it's a bad idea to mess around with those folders.  I think it might mess up Windows Update.  Sorry to be so vague, but I thought I should weigh in before you do something drastic.  I'll look for that article and post a link if I find it.  Is there some specific reason you want to remove them, other than to save drive space or that you're just obsessive about what's on your drive?

Comment: I think you're talking about the feature in Vista (Win2008)+ where it keeps all previous versions of updates in case they're requested by an app.

Answer (score -1):

XP's built-in Add/Remove Programs control panel applet will show Windows hotfixes if you check "Show Updates". They are under "Windows XP - Software Updates". You can get further info about each one by clicking "Click here for support information".